# Problem mapview in activitygroup

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-tabhost

I have an app write follow structure activitygroup. Every Tabhost contain a mapview. But when press another tab after back old tab the mapview did not auto refresh. Mapview just refresh when i touch screen. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: put your code here for better solution

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the mapview within the activities onResume() method. It does not call onCreate again once the activity has already been created.